# How to write a RewriteRule to redirect from specific query string?

Tags: regex, apache

I have A list of different Query-IDs needed to be redirectd to other Sites and pages. Like:

```
RewriteRule ^/index.php?id=1111$ http://newdomain.tld/site.html [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^/index.php?id=2222$ http://nextdomain.tld/othersite.html [R=301,L,NE]
```

But this example does not work as the source contains a query string. I am a bit stuck. Hopefully the solution is quite simple, but can you help me`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For query string you have to use below rule with condition, this is one example, I am assuming you can create multiple optimized rules using below.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1111$
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.tld/site.html [R=301,L,NE]
```